# Bind Multiple Models on a View in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to have 3 models in 1 view. The page contains both PhieuMuonSach(Model) and CTPhieuMuonSach(Model).

**PhieuMuonSach(Model):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("PhieuMuonSach")]
public partial class PhieuMuonSach
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PhieuMuonSach()
    {
        CTPhieuMuonSach = new HashSet<CTPhieuMuonSach>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id_PhieuMuon { get; set; }

    public int? Id_DocGia { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? NgayMuon { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CTPhieuMuonSach> CTPhieuMuonSach { get; set; }

    public virtual TheDocGia TheDocGia { get; set; }
}
```

**CTPhieuMuonSach(Model):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("CTPhieuMuonSach")]
public partial class CTPhieuMuonSach
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id_PhieuMuon { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id_Sach { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? NgayTra { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TrangThai { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string GhiChu { get; set; }

    public virtual PhieuMuonSach PhieuMuonSach { get; set; }

    public virtual Sach Sach { get; set; }
}
```

**Sach(Model):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("Sach")]
public partial class Sach
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Sach()
    {
        CTPhieuMuonSach = new HashSet<CTPhieuMuonSach>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id_Sach { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string TenSach { get; set; }

    public int? Id_Loai { get; set; }

    public int? Id_TacGia { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? NgayNhap { get; set; }

    public int? SoLuong { get; set; }

    public double? DonGiaNhap { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string NhaXuatBan { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? NamXuatBan { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string TinhTrang { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CTPhieuMuonSach> CTPhieuMuonSach { get; set; }

    public virtual LoaiSach LoaiSach { get; set; }

    public virtual TacGia TacGia { get; set; }
}
```

**QuanLyMuonTraSach(Model):**

```
   public class QuanLyMuonTraSach
{

    //public PhieuMuonSach PhieuMuonSach { get; set; }


    //public CTPhieuMuonSach CTPhieuMuonSach { get; set; }

    //public Sach Sach { get; set; }


    public List<PhieuMuonSach> PhieuMuonSach { get; set; }


    public List<CTPhieuMuonSach> CTPhieuMuonSach { get; set; }

    public List<Sach> Sach { get; set; }
}
```

**and QuanLyMuonTraSachController:**

```
public class QuanLyMuonTraSachController : Controller
{
    // GET: QuanLyMuonTraSach
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        QuanLyMuonTraSach ql = new QuanLyMuonTraSach();
        ql.PhieuMuonSach = GetPhieuMuonSach();
        ql.CTPhieuMuonSach = GetCTPhieuMuonSach();
        ql.Sach = GetSach();
        return View(ql);


    }

    //public PhieuMuonSach GetPhieuMuonSach()
    //{
    //    PhieuMuonSach pm = new PhieuMuonSach();
    //    return pm;


    //}

    //public CTPhieuMuonSach GetCTPhieuMuonSach()
    //{
    //    CTPhieuMuonSach ctpm = new CTPhieuMuonSach();
    //    return ctpm;

    //}

    //public Sach GetSach()
    //{
    //    Sach s = new Sach();
    //    return s;


    //}

    public List<PhieuMuonSach> GetPhieuMuonSach()
    {
        //PhieuMuonSach pm = new PhieuMuonSach();
        //return pm;
        return new List<PhieuMuonSach>();

    }

    public List<CTPhieuMuonSach> GetCTPhieuMuonSach()
    {
        //CTPhieuMuonSach ctpm = new CTPhieuMuonSach();
        //return ctpm;
        return new List<CTPhieuMuonSach>();
    }

    public List<Sach> GetSach()
    {
        //PhieuMuonSach pm = new PhieuMuonSach();
        //return pm;
        return new List<Sach>();

    }
```

***When I create view for *QuanLyMuonTraSachController* with Template "List", the error appears as shown below:***
[When I create view for *QuanLyMuonTraSachController* with Template "List", the error appears as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oLHc.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c15VF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oLHc.png)

Please Help Me, Thank you! :(

Comment: Your `public class QuanLyMuonTraSach` needs to be in a separate folder (say `ViewModels`) so it is not associated with EF

Comment: Since you are trying to create a composite of tables, it's asking a key be defined on top of it as well.. However the underlying classes seem to be taken as ORM one, so ideally here you should create business equivalent classes here, which don't have the Table details (srp principles). Here it's trying to enforce a database type relationships which is not exactly the case.. Or may be..

Comment: Apart, is the error coming on binding with view or while populating the object itself...? Can you validate all properties as valid before object being passed to the view?

Comment: I'd say you don't have to select list Template because you're passing a single QuanLyMuonTraSach object. Then when the page will be created, you'll need some foreach. But do it later